# How to know the type of each property in a Firestore document?

Tags: java, android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have this db:

```
root
 \_ users
     \_ uid
         \_ name: "Pathis"
         \_ admin: true
     \_ uid
         \_ name: "Venkat"
         \_ admin: false
```

Code to get the data:

```
db.collection("users").whereEqualTo("admin", true).get().addOnCompleteListener(task -> {
    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
        for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
            boolean admin = document.getBoolean("admin");
        }
    }
});
```

It works because I know the types (name is a String, admin is a boolean). But how would this work if I did not know them? What I need is a way to get the document and verify each property. Let's say I find name and I would like to verify as String type, I find admin and I should get boolean. Is there a solution for this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you don't know the type of value ahead of time, you will have to access the value as an Object using [get()](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#get(java.lang.String)), then check its type using the Java `instanceof` operator.  For example:

```
Object adminObject = document.get("admin");
if (adminObject instanceof String) {
    String admin = (String) adminObject;
}
else if (adminObject instanceof Boolean) {
    boolean admin = (Boolean) adminObject;
}
```

This is not an exhaustive approach - just a short example.  You might need to handle many other types, and your code might need to adapt.

Comment: Thank you for taking the time to answer this question. When I said "would this work if I did not know them" I'm referring not knowing them at all. In my example I know the property is named admin but what if I don't know that. I need this for any type of documents without knowing the name of the properties. I have different collection with different data.

Comment: If you don't know the names at all, then you can just get a Map of all of the field names and value with `getData()` and do what you want with that map.  https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/android/com/google/firebase/firestore/DocumentSnapshot#getData()

Comment: I see I can use getData(). So I need to iterate to get the name of the fields and then use `document.get("propertyName")`, is this what you say?

Comment: Thank you very much.